# In Python, when should an object be passed as an argument as opposed to calling the method on object with the dot operator?

Tags: python

I understand that the dot operator is accessing the method specific to an object that is an instance of the class containing that method/function. However, in which cases do you instead call the function directly on an object, in the form `func(obj)` as opposed to `obj.func()`?
Can both techniques always be implemented (at least in custom code) or are there certain cases in which the former should be used over the latter, and vice versa?

I had previously read that the form `func(obj)` is for processing data that the object holds, but why would this not be possible with doing `obj.dataMember.func()`, is there an advantage to passing just the object, such as some change in mutability?

Comment: I don't know much about Python but isn't it mostly a global rule that functions out-of-scope (meaning your class's method) create an error?

Comment: With `obj.func()` then `func` is a member of the class which `obj` is an instance of.  With `func(obj)` then `func` is a global function.

Comment: Generally you make a function a class method if it does work with the internal state of the class or you're creating a related, logical grouping of functions.

Comment: @cdarke Thanks, that helps. As for the second part of the question, does this mean that the instances where each are used are always dictated by the way the function was written (instance function vs. global)?

Comment: Yes.  As @Prune says, an object method (pedantically, not the same as a function) has access to "private" attributes, those named with a double underscore prefix (private attributes can be accessed outside a class, but nice people don't do that).  Sorry for the delay, different timezone.

Answer (score 3):

If the function exists *exclusively* to serve that object type, then you should probably make it a method of the class; that requires the `obj.func()` syntax.

If the function will also work on objects *not* of that one class, then you should make it a regular function, performing the generalization and discrimination with the function.  This requires the syntax `func(obj)`.

Comment: Very concise and helpful, really helped me understand. Thanks for this answer.